# What causes this diamond to appear from a single Raptor engine firing?

Tags: spacex, raptor

[image: Still:]As seen on this video posted by Elon Musk

https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1154629726914220032?s=19

Comment: Can you update your question and include a still image of what you are asking about? Not everyone will take the time to go to twitter and watch a video.

Comment: ah yeah great idea. Doing that now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a [shock diamond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_diamond).  Commonly seen in jet and rocket exhaust.

[image]

There's a good explanation of the physics behind the diamonds [here](http://www.aerospaceweb.org/question/propulsion/q0224.shtml).  Short summary: If the pressure at the exit of the engine doesn't match the ambient pressure, then shock waves will form and reflect throughout the plume, causing the diamond patterns.

Comment: Awesome! thank you, does the Merlin produce these as well? 45 raptors at once is going to be quite pretty

Comment: It probably does - I'm not very familiar with Merlins - but since it uses kerosene as fuel the exhaust is a lot "yellower" and not as transparent, so it's harder to see them.